# How to update specific field in database with request laravel

Tags: php, laravel, oop, laravel-5, request

I want to update 2 or 3 field in my database how I can do it?
Here what I tried..

```
public function UpdateSingle(Request $request, $id)
{
$single = Single::find($id);
 if($single){
  $input = $request->all();
   if(!$request->artist) {
    $input['single_name'] = $request->input('single_name');
    $input['release_date'] = $request->input('release_date');
    $singles = $single->where('id', $id)->update($input);
   }
 }
}
```

In request it generate 5 requests, But I only need 3 request.

code above give me error like this

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'file' in 'field list'

Comment: have you tried to take your inputs using `$input = $request->only(['single_name', 'release_date', 'artist']);`?

Comment: nope, ill try it now..

Comment: its working, thanks

Comment: create a answer, so i can accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just take the inputs you need from the request like the following:

```
$input = $request->only(['single_name', 'release_date', 'artist']);
```